# How to add newly created item to array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular app with a create function that adds a movie:

```
createMovie(movie: Movie): void {
  this._dataService.createMovie<Movie>({'id': 20, 'name': 'Star Wars'})
  .subscribe((data) => this.movie = data,
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
      console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

This calls the createMovie() function in the service:

```
public createMovie<T>(movie: Movie): Observable<T> {
    console.log(movie);
    return this.http.post<T>('/api/movies/', movie);
}
```

It's working fine. I can see that added object in the database and on a refresh on the page.

In my app.component.ts I have a `movies: Movie[];`

What is the correct way of adding the newly created movie to that array?

Comment: just simple javascript.. should be movies.push(movie)

Comment: upvote for @bgraham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the `createMovie()` method in your **app.component** to:

```
createMovie(movie: Movie): void {
  this._dataService.createMovie<Movie>({'id': 20, 'name': 'Star Wars'})
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.movie = data;
      this.movies.push(this.movie); // <- adding the new movie to the movies array
    },
    (err) => {
      // Error handling
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.movies);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `movies.push(movie)`. or use the spread operator "..." like `[...movies, movie]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
//Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango

fruits.push("Kiwi");
//Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango,Kiwi
```